# variable initialised in bolt's constructor coming up as null

Tags: java, apache-storm

trying to create a custom bolt by using instance variables and initialising them in the constructor.

not sure why the values turn up as null when the topology is submitted.

If i try to mark those variable as 'final' the values are persisted and otherwise not.

all the ref/variable used is serializable.

using storm version 1.0.2

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = -1243523331733334733L;
String configPrefix;
OutputCollector collector;
ObjectMapper mapper;


public KafkaPushBolt(String configPrefix) {
    this.configPrefix = configPrefix;
}
```

...in @prepare method the value of configPrefix is coming as null, if declared as 'final' then it works

in the documentation there is no mention that the variable has to be declared final to persist value

'To customize a bolt, you should set parameters in its constructor and save them as instance variables so they will be serialized when submitting the bolt to the cluster'

expected value should not be null in case we initialise it with a parameterised constructor

Answer (score 0):

I tried this out on the latest snapshot of Storm 2.2.0, and am not seeing this behavior.

Here is my bolt:

```
public static class ExclamationBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
        private String someString;
        OutputCollector collector;

        public ExclamationBolt(String someString) {
            this.someString = someString;
        }



        @Override
        public void prepare(Map<String, Object> conf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
            this.collector = collector;
        }

        @Override
        public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
            LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass()).info("The string is {}", someString);
        }

    }
```

which prints "The string is world"

If only final fields are being transferred in 1.x, that is not intentional. Consider upgrading to 2.x.